# Environment variables for PHP applications

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5, environment-variables

A PHP application requires me to set several environment variables with things like database credentials, SMTP server, etc.

Examples of variables include:

```
FOO_DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:pass@host:3306/dbname
FOO_SMTP_SERVER=smtp://user:pass@host:25
FOO_FILE_PATH=/var/www/foo
FOO_URL_HOST=example.org
FOO_URL_PATH=/foo
```

**Where is the appropriate place to set these variables?**

Initially I tried setting them in `~/.profile` but I realized that I'm not the user that Apache runs as so that wouldn't work. I've found `/etc/environment` but I'm not sure if that's the appropriate place to be setting them. Currently there's only `PATH` there. If I set them there do I need to prefix the lines with `export`?

The documentation states that ENV files should be avoided in production to maximize performance. I'd also like to avoid using Apache's `SetEnv` and `PassEnv` directives if possible.

My production server is CentOS, however I'd like to know how to do this on Linux Mint and Ubuntu as well even though I currently use an ENV file for development.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put that `.env` file in the root folder of your project. Just make sure it's not publicly accessible.

This is what [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration) does but if you have concerns about performance and/or security you might take a look at [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).